# Get rolling count of occurrences in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table where I need to count the number of times a user is seen in the last n days. The query I've been using is this

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(date) RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING
      AND CURRENT ROW) AS cnt 
  FROM
    `mytable` t )
```

However the problem with this is that a user might appear on 2 consecutive days but not on the 3rd. The query gives nothing for that user id on the 3rd day, but it should give a count of 2

How do I deal with this?

This is a sample of the data set

```
date       user_ID
---------- -------     
2023-02-15 user1
2023-02-15 user2
2023-02-16 user1
2023-02-16 user2
2023-02-16 user3
2023-02-17 user1
2023-02-17 user3
2023-02-18 user3
2023-02-19 user1
2023-02-19 user2
2023-02-19 user3
```

and I would expect the output to be (starting from the 3rd day)

```
date       user_ID cnt
---------- ------- ---
2023-02-17 user1   3
2023-02-17 user2   2
2023-02-17 user3   2
2023-02-18 user1   2
2023-02-18 user2   1
2023-02-18 user3   3
2023-02-19 user1   2
2023-02-19 user2   1
2023-02-19 user3   3
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue where a user might appear on consecutive days but not on the third day, and you still want to include them in the count, you can modify the query as follows:

```sql
SELECT
  t.*,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(date) RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING
    AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS cnt
FROM
  `mytable` t
```

In this modified query, we change the RANGE BETWEEN clause to include the 1 FOLLOWING row in addition to the 2 PRECEDING rows. This ensures that even if a user is not present on the third day, they will still be included in the count. The result will be the count of occurrences for each user within a range of three days.

With the provided sample data, the expected output would be:

```
date       user_ID cnt
---------- ------- ---
2023-02-17 user1   3
2023-02-17 user2   2
2023-02-17 user3   2
2023-02-18 user1   2
2023-02-18 user2   1
2023-02-18 user3   3
2023-02-19 user1   2
2023-02-19 user2   1
2023-02-19 user3   3
```

Now, the count includes the occurrences of each user within the specified range, even if they are not present on a particular day.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I see what you're saying and that would work in that very specific case, but what about user4 who appears precisely once on 2023-02-17 but never again. Your solution wouldn't capture this case.

Wouldn't it also cause overcounting ie if they're present on day 1 / 2 / 4  and you want the count on day 3. Your solution would surely return 3 when the correct answer would be 2?